# カスタムビュー上のUIButtonのタップアクションをViewControllerで設定したい

Tags: ios, objective-c

以下のソースサンプルのように、カスタムビューのボタンのaddTargetメソッドをViewControllerに書きたいのですが、セレクターのメソッドが呼ばれません。

《試したこと》

1. カスタムビュー内にaddTargetメソッドを書いて、引数targetをnilにしてtapButton:を呼び出すように書くと動きましたが、警告が出ますし、tapButtonというメソッド名をViewController側で自由に決めることができないので、違うと思います。
2. サイズの関係で動かない場合もあるということで、backView、descriptionView、descriptionView.buttonの各frameをNSLogで表示させましたが、buttonだけ{0,0},{0,0}でした。

サンプルソースの(※)でもbutton.backgroundColorへの設定が反映されていませんし、どうやらbuttonのプロパティにアクセスできていないことが原因と考えましたが、理由が分かりません。

何かおかしなことをしてしまっているのでしょうか。

---

カスタムビュー

```
@interface DescriptionView : UIView

@property (weak) UIButton *button;
@property NSString *buttonStr;

@end

@implementation DescriptionView

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIButton *closeButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
    [closeButton setTitle:_buttonStr forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    closeButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, CGRectGetMaxY(rect)-40, rect.size.width, 40);
    _button = closeButton;
    [self addSubview:closeButton];

}
```

ViewController

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    // TableViewを置いてます。ちなみにサイズは画面サイズ。

    // カスタムビューの背面にくる土台ビュー
    UIView *backView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:_tableView.frame];
    backView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.4];
    backView.alpha = 0;
    backView.tag = VIEW_INFO;
    [self.view addSubview:backView];

    //カスタムビュー
    DescriptionView *descriptionView = [[DescriptionView alloc]init];
    descriptionView.buttonStr = @"next"; // <-これは反映される
    descriptionView.button.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];　// <-(※)これは反映されない
    [descriptionView.button addTarget:self action:@selector(tapButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    descriptionView.frame = CGRectInset(_tableView.frame, 20, 30);
    [backView addSubview:descriptionView];
    //だんだん表す
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.8 animations:^{
        backView.alpha = 1;
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ボタンを`drawRect:`で生成しているのが原因だと思います。`drawRect:`はシステムからビューの表示のために何度も呼ばれるメソッドです。現在のコードでは、`drawRect:`が呼ばれるたびに新しくボタンが作られて上書きされています。
つまり`viewDidLoad`でアクションメソッドを設定したボタンのインスタンスは、`drawRect:`が呼ばれることで上書きされて、別のボタンに変わってしまいます。

`viewDidLoad`と`drawRect:`にブレークポイントやログを出力するなどして、どのような順序で呼ばれているか、確かめてみるとわかると思います。

解決法としては、ボタンの生成を`init`などに移して、上書きされないようにします。